# Meteor:Accessing dynamically generted property name of object

Tags: meteor

How to iterate through an array of objects in a template where property name is dynamically generated.

"Array": [
            {
                "a": "1"
            },
            {
                "b": "2"
            },
            {
                "c": "3"
            }
        ]
Property names a, b, c are dynamically generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your array is just that, an array. So to iterate through each object you can do `yourArray.forEach(a => console.log(a))`

```
Object {a: "1"}
Object {b: "2"}
Object {c: "3"}
```

If you are wishing to access a property via a variable, you can do `yourObject[stringThatResolvesToDynamicProperty]`

You can use `Object.keys` to 'return an array of a given object's own enumerable properties'. So something like this to print out first property name of each object.

`yourArray.forEach(a => console.log(Object.keys(a)[0]))`

```
a
b
c
```

So, with this you can return the values if that is what you truly need.

`yourArray.forEach(a => console.log(a[Object.keys(a)[0]]))`

```
1
2
3
```